# Unbound variable when running script on embedded device?

Tags: bash

I have a [script](https://sentry.io/get-cli/) that works fine normally, when triggered on my desktop `curl -sL https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash`.

When I call the same `curl` command above but from an embedded device I get:

```
bash: line 22: !DOWNLOAD_URL_LOOKUP: unbound variable
```

Why does this only happen on the older embedded device? *(Ubuntu 14.04, GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf))*

---

**Related script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Darwin_x86_64="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Darwin-x86_64"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Linux_i686="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Linux-i686"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Linux_x86_64="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Linux-x86_64"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Windows_i686="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Windows-i686.exe"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Windows_x86_64="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Windows-x86_64.exe"
VERSION="1.26.0"
PLATFORM=`uname -s`
ARCH=`uname -m`

# If the install directory is not set, set it to a default
if [ -z ${INSTALL_DIR+x} ]; then
  INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/bin
fi
if [ -z ${INSTALL_PATH+x} ]; then
  INSTALL_PATH="${INSTALL_DIR}/sentry-cli"
fi

DOWNLOAD_URL_LOOKUP="SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_${PLATFORM}_${ARCH}"
DOWNLOAD_URL="${!DOWNLOAD_URL_LOOKUP}"

echo "This script will automatically install sentry-cli ${VERSION} for you."
echo "Installation path: ${INSTALL_PATH}"
if [ "x$(id -u)" == "x0" ]; then
  echo "Warning: this script is currently running as root. This is dangerous. "
  echo "         Instead run it as normal user. We will sudo as needed."
fi

if [ -f "$INSTALL_PATH" ]; then
  echo "error: sentry-cli is already installed."
  exit 1
fi

if [ x$DOWNLOAD_URL == x ]; then
  echo "error: your platform and architecture (${PLATFORM}-${ARCH}) is unsupported."
  exit 1
fi

if ! hash curl 2> /dev/null; then
  echo "error: you do not have 'curl' installed which is required for this script."
  exit 1
fi

TEMP_FILE=`mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/.sentrycli.XXXXXXXX"`

cleanup() {
  rm -f "$TEMP_FILE"
}

trap cleanup EXIT
curl -SL --progress-bar "$DOWNLOAD_URL" > "$TEMP_FILE"
chmod 0755 "$TEMP_FILE"
if ! mv "$TEMP_FILE" "$INSTALL_PATH" 2> /dev/null; then
  sudo -k mv "$TEMP_FILE" "$INSTALL_PATH"
fi

echo 'Done!'
```

Comment: Is the `DOWNLOAD_URL_LOOKUP` variable set? Maybe it's in your environment but not in/on the devices'?

Comment: @JeffSchaller it is set to `DOWNLOAD_URL_LOOKUP="SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_${PLATFORM}_${ARCH}"` where the 2 variables used are based on `uname -s` and `uname -m` going to test those commands on the device.

Comment: You could stave off questions like mine by including the script in your question.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I did link it but I will post the full script as text, since it will likely get updated if we find a fix :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much info to go on here, but did you source the variables? If so, then try to disable variable strictness for the sourced file by calling `set +u` just before you source the file, then enable it immediately afterwords with `set -u`

Comment: If you look at the script none of the variables used are assumed to be set. They are all set within the script itself no? https://sentry.io/get-cli/

Comment: You were right I wasn't familiar with variable indirect expansion syntax so I was surprised an unset variable was being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what is happening. `DOWNLOAD_URL_LOOKUP` gets set to `SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Linux_armv7l`.

Then the line:

```
 DOWNLOAD_URL="${!DOWNLOAD_URL_LOOKUP}"
```

Tries to map the `DOWNLOAD_URL` based on the variables set at the start:

```
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Darwin_x86_64="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Darwin-x86_64"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Linux_i686="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Linux-i686"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Linux_x86_64="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Linux-x86_64"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Windows_i686="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Windows-i686.exe"
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Windows_x86_64="https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/1.26.0/sentry-cli-Windows-x86_64.exe"
```

As these don't include `SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Linux_armv7l` the error is returned. If I add a url for my version the script runs:

```
SENTRY_DOWNLOAD_Linux_arm7l="https://google.com"
```

---

*Also it seems the script had an error message for this situation but it `set -u` causing the program to exit when an unset variable was referenced.*